# User databases inaccessible after physical restart

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, permissions

We have an unusual error happening on the SQL Server.

After restarting the physical server where the SQL Server instance is installed, the user databases are not accessible. System databases are accessible.

Please see screenshot (After right clicking on DB and choosing properties) as example and error at bottom of the page.

[image]

I did find this note, however the owner field was already populated. 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suhde/archive/2009/04/05/property-owner-is-not-available-for-database-dbname.aspx

However, the most interesting part is that when I restart the SQL Server instance, the user databases become accessible and no error is returned anymore. Everything functions as normal. This is done by logging into SSMS as 'sa' user.

I have tried to add additional permissions to the MDF, LDF and database location files, but haven't had much luck.
I will mention that the User Databases (`D:\Data` | `D:\Logs`) are in a different location to the System Databases (`C:\ Default Location`), although on the same server/network.

The SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service logs on as NT Service\MSSQLSERVER.

SQL Server version is:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)  Feb 10 2012 19:39:15
>
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on
>
> Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Error:

> Property Size is not available for Database '[xxxxx]'. This property
>   may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to
>   insufficient access rights.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

Comment: What is the version of Management Studio you are using (Help > About)?

Comment: Hi Aaron, apologies for the delay, it is 11.0.2100.60.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me as if the D: drive isn't accessible when the SQL service starts. Consider telling the service to start on a delayed start, or create a process which checks for a file on D: before doing a "net start mssqlserver".

Comment: Thanks Rob, the delayed start worked a treat, as long as I did it for the Agent as well.

Comment: Excellent news. And yes, Agent needs to start after SQL.